# Do something infinitely many times with an index

Tags: ruby, infinity, lazy-sequences

In [more ruby way of doing project euler #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029392/more-ruby-way-of-doing-project-euler-2) , part of the code is

```
while((v = fib(i)) < 4_000_000)
  s+=v if v%2==0
  i+=1
end
```

Is there a way to change `i += 1` into a more functional programming style construct?

The best I can think of is

```
Float::MAX.to_i.times do |i|
  v = fib(i)
  break unless v < 4_000_000
  s += v if v%2==0
end
```

because you can't call `.times` on a floating point number.

Comment: What's `Float` got to do with it in the first place? It's all integers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373343/math-infinity-in-ruby-how-do-i-iterate-over-an-infinite-sequence

Comment: @DanielFischer: Because I can't find an integer equivalent of FLOAT::MAX.

Comment: Ah, okay, I was afraid you were using floating point to calculate the Fibonacci numbers. But can't you do something like `sum . filter even . takeWhile (< 4000000) $ fibs` in ruby? Generate the infinite sequence lazily and consume what you need?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Numeric.step](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Numeric.html#method-i-step) has default parameters of infinity (the limit) and 1 (the step size).

```
1.step do |i|
  #...
end
```

For fun, you might even want to try

```
1.step.size
```

Comment: FWIW the above seems to work for Ruby 2.1 and 2.2 and up (I didn't try 2.0)

The Ruby 1.9.3 equivalent is 

1.step(Float::INFINITY, 1) {|i| ... }

Answer (score 12):

There’s a predefined (in 1.9.2) constant `Float::INFINITY`, so you could write

```
1.upto(Float::INFINITY) do |i|
  ...
end
```

(You could also use `Enumerator` and `take_while`, turning the problem inside out to make it look more like Haskell or Python, but `take_while` is greedy and builds an array.)

Answer (score 5):

Ruby 2.5 introduced the open-ended Range:

```
(1..).each do |i|
  #...
end
```